# Disable new left click spelling suggestions in Microsoft Word

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, office365

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/click-directly-on-spelling-and-grammar-for-corrections-1e72a440-89a6-457c-bd76-cd5cea901dc0?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us

This behaviour is not very optimal for some people, and the changelog states it will increase efficiency for people who find right-clicking inconvenient. Is there any way to disable this behaviour? Looking through the Proofing settings finds nothing, and the only other idea I have is to downgrade to a version before November 2020 Version 2010 (Build 13328.20210).

If there is an option to disable the new Editor interface and just leave the classic spellcheck, that is welcome too.

Comment: I am afraid your need is unable to be achieved currently. Please refer to **Jay Freedman**'s reply in thread "[How to disable spelling suggestions on left click?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-disable-spelling-suggestions-on-left-click/d5bddf98-b4f4-4702-b774-8dff79aa858d)".

Comment: You can add the legacy spelling checker to respond to the F7 key instead of the Editor but I know of nothing to get rid of this new "feature." https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/classic-spell-check-dialog-macro-to-use-to-get/a53fff0c-f15d-4150-95d6-1724c6ddca91

Comment: I took a Word document and the newest version of Office 365. I created a spelling error. Left click still works. Right click was added. I don’t see how to remove that but I do not need to, either.